# Access a vector stored in another vector in verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I want to access elements (8 bits long) stored in an "array", then do a logic AND with some switches. So far, not working:

```
module top(SW, LED);

input [15:0] SW;
output [15:0] LED;

logic [4:0] q = {8'b11101000,
8'b10011000,
8'b10100010,
8'b10110110,
8'b10000101
};

assign LED[7:0] = q[0] & SW[7:0];    
endmodule
```

I expect to have 8'b11101000 & SW[7:0] but clearly I'm not having that because of the result I'm seeing on the leds.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `logic [7:0] q [4:0] = {...};`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
const logic [4:0] q[5] = {8'b11101000,
                          8'b10011000,
                          8'b10100010,
                          8'b10110110,
                          8'b10000101
};
```